# What is wrong with the way I input Dates with the scaleTime() function in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3, Javascript, HTML and the function d3.scaleTime()

What is wrong with the way I input Dates with the scaleTime() function in d3?

I am currently trying to make an x-axis with d3, based on time using d3.scaleTime().
However whenever i input the timeData to scaleTime.domain() no data shows on my axis. 
I get a blank axis. 
[image]

The section of code I think my bug is coming from is here:

```
let timeData = ["2020-10-05", "2000-10-04"]

d3.scaleTime()
.domain( [timeData[0], timeData[1] ) 
.range( [0,400] )
```

I have tried changing timeData to `[2020-10-05, 2000-10-04]` 
However I then get decimal points on my axis.

[image]

any help is appreciated

Comment: Could your provide an example? It would help to better understand.

Comment: There is an example?

Comment: Sorry I meant a working example that would help to reproduce. I'm able to generate an axis on my side without issue that's why I'm asking. You can create on CodeSandbox easily.

Comment: The dates need to be passed as `Date` objects. Something like `.domain([new Date(timeData[0]), new Date(timeData[1])]) ` will do. Alternatively, you could use a date parser from the [d3-time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass min and max values as Date Formats on scaleTime.

```
d3.scaleTime()
.domain( new Date(timeData[0]), new Date(timeData[1]) ) 
.range( [0,400] )
```

Also note that min value is lesser than max value.

Reason its not working is that it is considering them as String values.